# Apply calculation referring to last 365 days data prior to current date

Tags: r, time-series

I have a `data.frame` that looks like this:

```
ACCOUNT  POSTING_DT  WA  Amount
  10019   1/10/2006  19    99.1
  10019   6/18/2007  15   318.5
  10019    7/2/2007  12 23005.1
  10019   3/25/2008  15 16866.3
  10019   9/22/2008  -1 16902.3
  10121   4/18/2006   1 28029.9
  10121   5/28/2006   3   16528
  10121   3/20/2007   1 41730.1
```

Each account has different posting date, and these dates are not continuous. I want to apply the calculation `sum(WA*Amount)/sum(Amount)` using items 365 days prior to the current posting date.

e.g.  for account `10019`, for `3/25/2008` item, I want to apply that calculation using `6/18/2007` and `7/2/2007` items , which will be `(15*318.5+12*23005.1)/(318.5+23005.1)`.

Is there a function in R to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know of a function that does what you want; frankly, I'd be a bit surprised since it's a bit "niche", but it's possible.

Your data:

```
txt <- 'ACCOUNT  POSTING_DT  WA  Amount
  10019   1/10/2006  19    99.1
  10019   6/18/2007  15   318.5
  10019    7/2/2007  12 23005.1
  10019   3/25/2008  15 16866.3
  10019   9/22/2008  -1 16902.3
  10121   4/18/2006   1 28029.9
  10121   5/28/2006   3   16528
  10121   3/20/2007   1 41730.1'
dat <- read.table(text=txt, header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

The date column really should be as a `Date` object vice a string, so ...

```
dat$POSTING_DT <- as.Date(dat$POSTING_DT, format='%m/%d/%Y')
```

Here goes:

```
dat$NewAmount <- sapply(1:nrow(dat), function(r) {
    d <- (dat$POSTING_DT[r] - dat$POSTING_DT)
    ## I use both (d>=0) and idx[r] <- FALSE so that if there are multiple
    ## instances on a day, the other ones will still be included
    idx <- (dat$ACCOUNT == dat$ACCOUNT[r]) & (d >= 0) & (d <= 365)
    idx[r] <- FALSE
    ## the crux of this function ("with" is not required but it reads well)
    with(dat, sum(WA[idx] * Amount[idx]) / sum(Amount[idx]))
})
dat
##   ACCOUNT POSTING_DT WA  Amount NewAmount
## 1   10019 2006-01-10 19    99.1       NaN
## 2   10019 2007-06-18 15   318.5       NaN
## 3   10019 2007-07-02 12 23005.1 15.000000
## 4   10019 2008-03-25 15 16866.3 12.040967
## 5   10019 2008-09-22 -1 16902.3 15.000000
## 6   10121 2006-04-18  1 28029.9       NaN
## 7   10121 2006-05-28  3 16528.0  1.000000
## 8   10121 2007-03-20  1 41730.1  1.741866
```

You didn't say what should happen with empty sets. If you need them set to zero, you can do:

```
dat$NewAmount <- pmax(dat$NewAmount, 0, na.rm=TRUE)
dat
##   ACCOUNT POSTING_DT WA  Amount NewAmount
## 1   10019 2006-01-10 19    99.1  0.000000
## 2   10019 2007-06-18 15   318.5  0.000000
## 3   10019 2007-07-02 12 23005.1 15.000000
## 4   10019 2008-03-25 15 16866.3 12.040967
## 5   10019 2008-09-22 -1 16902.3 15.000000
## 6   10121 2006-04-18  1 28029.9  0.000000
## 7   10121 2006-05-28  3 16528.0  1.000000
## 8   10121 2007-03-20  1 41730.1  1.741866
```

**Edit**: *Untested*

With a lot of rows (157k as you said), assuming there are a sufficient number of rows per account, you might benefit from grouping things first. This can be done with base functions (`split`?), but I'll demonstrate `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
    group_by(ACCOUNT) %>%
    mutate(NewAmount = sapply(1:n(), function(r) {
        d <- (dat$POSTING_DT[r] - dat$POSTING_DT)
        idx <- (dat$ACCOUNT == dat$ACCOUNT[r]) & (d >= 0) & (d <= 365)
        idx[r] <- FALSE
        with(dat, sum(WA[idx] * Amount[idx]) / sum(Amount[idx]))
    }))
```

There's likely a more elegant `dplyr`-esque method, but doing things row-wise within a grouping doesn't seem to scream "easy efficiency" to me.

**Edit 2**:

Lacking `dplyr` (and even `devtools`!?!), try this `base`-version:

```
do.call("rbind", lapply(split(dat, dat$ACCOUNT), function(x) {
    x$NewAmount <- sapply(1:nrow(x), function(r) {
        d <- (x$POSTING_DT[r] - x$POSTING_DT)
        idx <- (x$ACCOUNT == x$ACCOUNT[r]) & (d >= 0) & (d <= 365)
        idx[r] <- FALSE
        with(x, sum(WA[idx] * Amount[idx]) / sum(Amount[idx]))
    }, USE.NAMES=FALSE)
    x
}))
```

I haven't done benchmarking or extensive testing, so caveat emptor.

Comment: Not sure how to (quickly) speed things up: since your requirements dictate "row-wise" computation, it sort of mandates some inefficiency. I'm confident it's possible to speed things up a bit, but if it is tolerable this time and isn't repeated often, then you're good. (*"Premature optimization is the root of all evil."* -Knuth)

Comment: thanks very much @ r2evans! my file has 157,252 items. the code has been running for over 5 minutes, is it normal?

Comment: No idea about your 403 error, it installs just fine for me (2 minutes ago, win10_64, R-3.2.3, dplyr-0.4.3). If by "already grouped" you mean "the rows are already near each other", that is *very* different from `dplyr`'s grouping (and does not improve performance like `dplyr::group_by` might).

Comment: ok. let me work on installing the dplyr first Thanks so very much for your time

Comment: If CRAN is still misbehaving for you, try `devtools::install_github("hadley/dplyr")`, though you'll get a development version (which has been working fine for me for a couple of months).

Comment: after I run your  dplyr code, why the new column did not show in the dat table when I View(dat)?

Comment: Assign it! `dat <- dat %>% ...` :-) (and I didn't know anyone actually used `View`!)

Comment: @ r2evans.  I got a problem. the code runs perfectly on small sample, but when runs on my whole file, the result is inconsistent. i must have missed something....  let me post a new one, because i have to attach snapshot.

Comment: I figured out why to my own question. I changed the account field to numeric instead of factor. it runs faster and result is correct!  thanks for your help!

Comment: Glad to hear it's working for you. Can you please "accept" this answer?